# Is Black Freezer the strongest warrior in the universe now?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

So in chapter 87 of the manga,

> Black Freezer defeats Gas, who was supposed to be the strongest warrior of the universe at the moment, though not sure if he was at full strenght, and Goku and Vegeta.

Does this mean Black Freezer is the strongest warrior in the universe now? How about Beast Gohan? Did he surpass Beast Gohan too?